# How to connect to two databases in rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

I need to create a rake task to migrate some information from an older web app to our new web app, so in the task I need to connect to two databases, how can I open a connection to another database without using active record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use mysql then you can do like this

```
require 'mysql'

mysql = Mysql.init()
mysql.connect('localhost')

mysql.select_db('test')

results = mysql.query("SELECT now();")

results.each{|row|; puts row;}

mysql.close()
```

Hope this will help you.